# why the ref after defgroup doesn't show in doxygen

Tags: doxygen, ref

Just like the following example:

```
   // ...
   @defgroup group_1 test_group_1 
   @{
       #### title 1 #####
   @}

   @ref group_1
   // ...
```

I used Doxygen GUI frontend to generate the html page, but it didn't show correctly, just is empty!

I show the another example that has the same problem:

```
   @ref group_1

   @defgroup group_1 test_group_1
   @{
        #### title 1 #####
   @}


   @ref group_2

   @defgroup group_2 test_group_2
   @{
        #### title 2 #####
   @}
```

And it's no doubt that in my case it only show group_1 reference!
But when I put all the group after the ref,it correctly shows all refs, like the following:

```
   @ref group_1

   @ref group_2

   @defgroup group_1 test_group_1
   @{
        #### title 1 #####
   @}

   @defgroup group_2 test_group_2
   @{
        #### title 2 #####
   @}
```

I want to put each group together with the corresponding ref just the second example shows, but I don't know why and how to solve!

thanks in advance!